# Reverse animation in mousemove Javascript event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, reverse, mousemove

I'm trying to animate a static background, but my issue was since I do not have such a big background image and **I do not want user to see the outer part of my background**.

To encounter this issue. I'm trying to reverse my **event.pageX** values when I reach 1280 and above, but I just cant figure out how to reverse the animation....

```
$("header .headerInnerWrapper").mousemove(function(event) {
var xPos = event.pageX;
console.log(xPos);

if(xPos>=1280){//reverse the number
    //will be 1279,1278, 1277.......
}

 bg.css('backgroundPosition', [xPos] + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("header .headerInnerWrapper").mousemove(function(event) {
var xPos = event.pageX;
console.log(xPos);

if(xPos>=1280){
    xPos = 2560 - xPos; // that would be 1280 - (xpos -1280);
}

 bg.css('backgroundPosition', [xPos] + "px");
});
```

or to work with all values:

```
$("header .headerInnerWrapper").mousemove(function(event) {
var xPos = event.pageX;
console.log(xPos);

if(xPos>=1280){
    xPos = Math.ceil(xPos/1280)*1280 - xPos; 
}

 bg.css('backgroundPosition', [xPos] + "px");
});
```